# Change the maximum screen size icon (and variable) by dragging the TitleBar

Tags: reactjs, electron, resize

In a desktop application (written in Electron), I'm trying to implement a feature that will allow the user to open the application in full screen or return it to the reverse state (initially the application does not open in full screen).

I already have working functionality.

What I've done:

main.ts

```
ipcMain.handle(IPCChannels.CheckMax, () => {
  let result = '';
  if (mainWindow.isMaximized()) {
    mainWindow.unmaximize();
    result = 'unmaximize';
    return result;
  }
  mainWindow.maximize();
  result = 'maximize';
  return result;
});
```

TitleBar.tsx

```
function TitleBar() {
  const [checkMax, setCheckMax] = useState('');

  function maximize() {
    window.electron.ipcRenderer
      .invoke(IPCChannels.CheckMax)
      .then((res) => setCheckMax(res))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <nav>
      <div/>
      <button onClick={maximize}>
        {checkMax === 'maximize' ? (
          <MaxIcon />
        ) : (
          <MinIcon />
        )}
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

That is, what happens from our code: I click on the button to change the screen size, the screen becomes maximum and the icon changes. Or vice versa, the screen appears with the previous sizes, and the icon changes again.

However, the problem is that the **result** variable (and the icons accordingly) only changes when I click on the button. In all applications, and you can verify this, you can exit the maximum screen size by pulling the TitleBar (try the example of Google Chrome or any browser or any application).
Please tell me how I can change the value of the **result** variable, including when I pull the TitleBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add window listeners on [`"maximize"`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-maximize) and [`"unmaximize"`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-unmaximize) events:

```js
mainWindow.on("maximize", () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.send("maximize");
});

mainWindow.on("unmaximize", () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.send("unmaximize");
});
```

And then set IPC listeners on you renderer to change the state of your button accordingly, for example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const maximize = () => setCheckMax("maximize"));
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.on("maximize", maximize);

  const unmaximize = () => setCheckMax("unmaximize");
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.on("unmaximize", unmaximize);

  return () => {
    window.electron.ipcRenderer.removeListener("maximize", maximize);
    window.electron.ipcRenderer.removeListener("unmaximize", unmaximize);
  };
}, []);
```

I used your code for the example, but please make sure you follow [security guidelines](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations) when using IPC.

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question! But since I just started studying the electron, I didn't quite understand your idea:
1) Which file should I add your first part of code to?
2) How should I influence onClick in the TitleBar.tsx file?

Perhaps you can integrate your code into my example and show it in more detail?

Comment: @Paul Your window declaration is on your main process, the the listeners go on the main process. And I thought you already had a working button? Just add the `useEffect` on your `<Titlebar>` component.

Comment: Yes, the button works. But when I try to use my code with yours, it doesn't work. Apparently I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @Paul What "doesn't work" means? I made a little typo on the remove listener of "unmaximize" (I fixed it now), check you didn't copied it or the listener won't be removed correctly. Otherwise, just adapt the code to your implementation. Your problem was to detect when the window state changes, using the events solves this problem.

Comment: I'll clarify: I should add your first part of code to the main.ts file instead of my code (which I demonstrated in the main.ts file)?

Comment: @Paul These are window events, you have to put them where your window declaration is, just like a "close" event to detect if your window is closed for example. That should be `main.ts` since I can see `mainWindow` on the code you shared.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: window.electron.ipcRenderer.removeListener is not a function"

Comment: @Paul I don't know what kind of implementation you have for IPC, I can only provide an example code based on what you shared. You have to adapt the code so it works for your implementation. Update your code so you can use IPC's [`removeListener`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener).

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I managed to achieve the result, only in my case I need to write window.electron.ipcRenderer.on(......) instead removeListener

Comment: @Paul As long as it removes the listener, you should be good. :)